# Cannot call a string altered by NSAttributedString since i'm no longer calling a String type

Tags: swift

I currently have various "prompts" which are string values in an array. I pull a random prompt from that array in the method below. Each string has an initial character, or identifier, which tells the ViewController what to label it as and then in the method I remove that first character.

```
@IBAction func showPrompt() {

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]

        if let selectedPrompt = promptProvider.randomPrompt() {

            if selectedPrompt.prefix(1) == "*" {
                    ShamblesCategory.text = "GROUP PLAY"
                    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1/255.0, green: 184/255.0, blue: 170/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                    ShamblesNewPromptButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 1/255.0, green: 184/255.0, blue: 170/255.0, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
                    ShamblesPrompt.text = selectedPrompt.replacingOccurrences(of: "[*|~@^]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
                    //green
                } else {
                if selectedPrompt.prefix(1) == "~" {
                        ShamblesCategory.text = "CALLOUT"
                        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 68/255.0, green: 141/255.0, blue: 202/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                        ShamblesNewPromptButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 68/255.0, green: 141/255.0, blue: 202/255.0, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
                        ShamblesPrompt.text = selectedPrompt.replacingOccurrences(of: "[*|~@^]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
                        //blue
                    } else {
                    if selectedPrompt.prefix(1) == "|" {
                            ShamblesCategory.text = "CHALLENGE"
                            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 253.0/255.0, green: 98.0/255.0, blue: 94.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                            ShamblesNewPromptButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 253.0/255.0, green: 98.0/255.0, blue: 94.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
                            ShamblesPrompt.text = selectedPrompt.replacingOccurrences(of: "[*|~@^]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
                            //red
                    } else {
                        if selectedPrompt.prefix(1) == "^" {
                            ShamblesCategory.text = "TEAMS"
                            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 247/255.0, green: 179/255.0, blue: 76/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                            ShamblesNewPromptButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 247/255.0, green: 179/255.0, blue: 76/255.0, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
                            paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
                            selectedPrompt.replacingOccurrences(of: "[*|~@^]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
                            var attributedPrompt = NSAttributedString(string: selectedPrompt, attributes: attributes)
                            ShamblesPrompt.text = attributedPrompt
                            //yellow
                        } else {
                            ShamblesCategory.text = "TEAMS"
                            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 247/255.0, green: 179/255.0, blue: 76/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                            ShamblesNewPromptButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 247/255.0, green: 179/255.0, blue: 76/255.0, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
                            ShamblesPrompt.text = selectedPrompt.replacingOccurrences(of: "[*|~@^]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

                            //yellow
                        }}}}
}
```

I'm attempting to left-align my label if the first character (the identifier) is "^", however I'm getting an error on the `ShamblesPrompt.text = attributedPrompt` line saying 'Cannot assign value of type 'NSAttributedString' to type 'String?''.

For clarification: `ShamblesPrompt` is a UILabel.

Any help on resolving this issue would be much appreciated (I also may be writing the NSAttributedString portion wrong since I'm a rookie and never used this class before).

Thank you

Comment: What is `ShamblesPrompt`? A `UILabel`? If so, you'll need to set the `attributedText`.

Comment: @nighttalker Yes, sorry, I'll edit the question. ```ShamblesPrompt``` is a UILabel. Can you elaborate on me needing to set the ```attributedText```

Comment: `ShamblesPrompt.attributedText = attributedPrompt`

Comment: Thanks @nighttalker however now I have two new issues: (1) ```selectedPrompt.replacingOccurrences(of: "[*|~@^]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)``` now doesn't do anything (ie it isn't removing the "^"). and (2) the prompt used to auto-size the font down to fit in the label but now it doesnt. Do you think I should be using a different strategy to change the alignment of the label?